# Using of Set Interval in React Native Android and iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native

Both [React Native Video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-vide) and timer (used setInterval) are worked on foreground and timer is stopped when app is in the background. But still video plays in the background.

It means, when the application pauses, so do all setInterval's running and (and setTimeouts pending).

headlessJs api is available only for android to run the task in background.

> If I use headlessJs, Isn't product pain for react native to run a timer?

---

**There are some desired libraries,**

[react-native-background-job](https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job) - Use headlessJs and work only in android.

[react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task) - Use headlessJs in android and ios uses a proxy around react-native-background-fetch library (Support only for a single task,The exact timings of task execution are unpredictable)

[react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch)

> Can I use setInterval in the background service if I use those libraries?
>
> Why only music player is working in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution from [react-native-background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) library.

In iOS, we can start the timer or do any react native stuff in the background after execute the following code.

Background timer works even we use other apps in the device. (Ex: itune, whatsup)

```
// Import the library
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';

// Start the timer
BackgroundTimer.start();

// Start a timer that runs continuous after X milliseconds
const intervalId = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {

// this will be executed every 200 ms
// even when app is the the background
console.log('tic');

}, 200);
```

In android,

```
// Import the library
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';

// Start a timer that runs continuous after X milliseconds
const intervalId = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {

   // this will be executed every 200 ms
   // even when app is the the background
   console.log('tic');
}, 200);
```

**Note:** Test with the device and don't trust the simulator